# Closing the database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, textview

Please help me where should I put the db.close () in this class, because when I put it at the end of class inside onPause method but it generates error and force stops the app , the problem happens when I click on the row , I want that a share menu popup when I click the row , the first time I click the row it pops the menu but for the second time I click on the row it force stops the app , when I remove the db.close () it is Ok but I know the db ahould be closed but I don't know where should I  close?
Here is the Class codes :

```
public class sharedlist extends ListActivity {

 private String[] items;
 private database db;

 private Typeface homa;
 private Typeface nazanin;
 private SharedPreferences sp;
 private Typeface god;


  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.sharedlist);


db=new database(this);
db.open();

items=new      String[db.Count("content")];

homa=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Font/homa.ttf");
nazanin=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Font/nazanin.ttf");
god=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Font/Godfather.ttf");
sp=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("setting", 0);

setListAdapter(new AAD());


}



  @Override
protected void   onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, db.Display_Shared(position, 2).toString());
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"اشتراک گذاری از طریق"));

  }

class AAD extends ArrayAdapter{

public AAD(){
    super(sharedlist.this , R.layout.row,items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater in=getLayoutInflater();
    View row=in.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

    TextView username= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_username);
    TextView maintext= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_maintext);

    username.setText(db.Display_Shared(position,1).toString());
    maintext.setText(db.Display_Shared(position, 2).toString());

    username.setTypeface(god);

    if(sp.getString("font", "homa").equals("nazanin")){


        maintext.setTypeface(nazanin);


    }else if(sp.getString("font", "homa").equals("homa")){

        maintext.setTypeface(homa);

    }


    if(sp.getString("size", "k").equals("k")){

        maintext.setTextSize(18);

    }else if(sp.getString("size", "k").equals("b")){

        maintext.setTextSize(25);

    }
    return (row);
}
}

  /*@Override
 protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
db.close();
}*/


  }
```

Comment: My advice is to close everything you open **as soon** as you used it. My mantra: `open, use, close`. I.E.: open, update a record, close - open, make a query, close - open, delete a record, close - open, execute a batch in a transaction, close....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you open a resource in an activity lifecycle method, you should close it in another lifecycle method for symmetry.

For example, if you open in onCreate, close in onDestroy.  If you open in onStart, close in onStop.

In your case, since you open in onCreate and use the opened db while the activity is running, you could close in onDestroy, which is supposed to be the very last method executed before the activity finishes.

Comment: I closed it in onDestroy method and my problem is solved I think

Answer (score 0):

You should set the db.close() in the onListItemClick() method. You got error, when you click on the row for the second time, because your database is closed. I think you should open your database in the onListItemClick() do your stuff, and close the database.

Comment: thanks bro your solution helped me too but I closed it in onDestroy method